# Unix/Linux shell variable issue

Tags: linux, shell

in Terminal, I enter the following code:

```
~$ a=1
~$ ${a}
```

it shows: 1: command not found

but when I echo the variable, it correctly shows 1.

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors. Also, this sounds more like a question for SuperUser.

Comment: So, where is your problem? It does exactly what one would expect. You even say, that echoing the variable outputs the value of the variable. Calling the variable will try to execute a binary which has the name of the variable's value.

Answer (score 3):

Telling the shell:

```
a=1
$a
```

Makes the shell look for the program with the name `1` in its path.

Telling it

```
a=1
echo $a
```

Tells the shell to look for the program `echo` which then takes your first argument (`1`) and print it to `stdout`.